# Writing a PLSQL Oracle function to query a table

Tags: oracle, function, stored-procedures, plsql

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE Book
(
book_id      INTEGER NOT NULL ,
isbn         VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
tittle       VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL ,
shelf_letter CHAR (1) NOT NULL ,
call_number  INTEGER ,
no_of_copies INTEGER NOT NULL ,
```

) ;

I need to write a function to retrieve `book_id, title,call_number, shelf_letter, no_of_copies` for a given `isbn`.

Input parameters: `isbn`

Output parameters: `title, no_of_copies,call_number,shelf_letter.`

Return `book_id` if the query is successful and -1 if not.

How can I properly write this function?

Comment: I'm new to plsql and I'm trying to solve this. I didn't understand what an Output parameter meant. I know what a traditional Function is (in C & Java) which takes 0 or more input parameters and return a value or just void. But I'm trying to get my head around PLSQL functions. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this can help you start http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#CHDBEJGF . When you'll have a specific problem, we'll all be glad to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create OR replace FUNCTION get_book_id 
(
  p_isbn            IN VARCHAR2
, po_title          OUT VARCHAR2
, po_no_of_copies   OUT NUMBER
, po_call_number    OUT NUMBER
, po_shelf_letter   OUT NUMBER
)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
  v_book_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
  BEGIN 
    SELECT 
        book_id
      , title         
      , no_of_copies  
      , call_number   
      , shelf_letter  
    INTO 
        v_book_id
      , po_title         
      , po_no_of_copies  
      , po_call_number   
      , po_shelf_letter  
    FROM book
    WHERE isbn = 'p_isbn'
    ;
  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    v_book_id := -1;
  END; 

  RETURN v_book_id;
END;
/
```

Comment: "Do not use OUT and IN OUT for function parameters." Oracle Database PL/SQL Language Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS659

Comment: @schurik, it's not "so bad" but this is the meaning of a function - "get some inputs and return one". This allows it to be called in a sql statement for example, if you add an OUT param it cannot http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a62d7/1 . You could however do this in a procedure

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
    TYPE book_info_rec IS RECORD
    (
        book_id      NUMBER(1)
    ,   title        VARCHAR2(30)
    ,   call_number  NUMBER(1)
    ,   shelf_letter VARCHAR2(30)
    ,   no_of_copies NUMBER(1)
    );

    l_book  book_info_rec;

    FUNCTION get_book_info(isbn_in IN VARCHAR2) RETURN book_info_rec
    AS
        l_book_info  book_info_rec;
    BEGIN
        SELECT  1
        ,       'A Book'
        ,       2
        ,       'A'
        ,       3
        INTO    l_book_info
        FROM    DUAL
        WHERE   dummy = isbn_in;

        RETURN l_book_info;
    END;
BEGIN
    l_book := get_book_info('X');

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE
    (
              l_book.book_id
    || ' ' || l_book.title
    || ' ' || l_book.call_number
    || ' ' || l_book.shelf_letter
    || ' ' || l_book.no_of_copies
    );
END;
```